# Syntax error in HAML if elsif

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, haml

I keep getting this error when i try to render a HAML partial:

```
app/views/shared/_notification.html.haml:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting keyword_end
app/views/shared/_notification.html.haml:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting keyword_end
app/views/shared/_notification.html.haml:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif, expecting end-of-input
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20:in `notify_in_realtime'
app/controllers/account/users_controller.rb:38:in `show'
```

When I try to render this view :

```
- if object.class.name == 'Lab'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
    = image_tag object.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = object.title
      = content

- elsif object.class.name == 'Post'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object.lab, :post => object.id), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
    = image_tag object.lab.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = object.lab.title
      = content

- elsif object.class.name == 'Comment'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object.post.lab, :comment => object.id), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
    = image_tag object.post.lab.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = object.post.lab.title
      = content

- elsif object.class.name == 'User'
  = link_to account_user_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
    = image_tag avatar_url(user, :thumb), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = object.full_name
      = content

- elsif object.class.name == Mailboxer::Conversation
  = link_to account_conversation_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
    = image_tag avatar_url(user, :thumb), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = user.full_name
      = content
.clearfix
```

Inside my application controller, where I am trying to store it in a variable to send it later:

```
html = render_to_string :partial => 'shared/notification', :locals => {content: content, user: user, object: object, notification: notification}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: Your if elsif is wrong, try to convert your haml file into erb in [link]https://haml2erb.org/ and you can notice that your syntax is if..end..elsif..end..elsif..end..end which is wrong. Remove the end before elsif (if..elsif..elsif..end) then convert it to [link]http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haml syntax is not correct

if you want image and .media-body inside the link, you should have `do` after `link_to`, else they should have the same level with link_to

```
- if object.class.name == 'Lab'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item" do
    = image_tag object.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
    .media-body
      %strong.name
        = object.title
      = content
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
- if object.class.name == 'Lab'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
  = image_tag object.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
  .media-body
    %strong.name
      = object.title
    = content
- elsif object.class.name == 'Comment'
  = link_to account_lab_path(object.post.lab, :comment => object.id), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
  = image_tag object.post.lab.picture.url(:medium), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
  .media-body
    %strong.name
      = object.post.lab.title
    = content
- elsif object.class.name == 'User'
  = link_to account_user_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
  = image_tag avatar_url(user, :thumb), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
  .media-body
    %strong.name
      = object.full_name
    = content
- elsif object.class.name == Mailboxer::Conversation
  = link_to account_conversation_path(object), "data-id" => notification.id.to_s, :class => "notification item"
  = image_tag avatar_url(user, :thumb), :class => "img-circle pull-left avatar"
  .media-body
    %strong.name
      = user.full_name
    = content
```

Try to convert your haml code into erb/html. You can notice that the structure is like:

```
<% if something %>
<% end %>
<% elsif somthing %>
<% end %>
<% elsif something %>
```

It should be:

```
`<% if something %>
<% elsif somthing %>
<% elsif something %>
<% end %>`
```

Comment: Ok,  I tried to replace my code with your second answer and it didn't work (wrong indent), I created an erb file and will test it soon.

Comment: You dont need to create an erb file if you are using haml. Like what I said, your if..elsif..end is wrong. Try to paste your code here [link]https://haml2erb.org/ and you'll notice the wrong if..elsif..end syntax.

Comment: The insertion of "end" inside your code may be the result of an extra line space.  Your "elsif"s should vertically align with the "if" they are a part of.

Comment: I modify the code snippet above. I think, indention is better.

Answer (score 0):

There's another potential problem with your code:

```
- elsif object.class.name == Mailboxer::Conversation
```

Should either be

```
- elsif object.class.name == 'Mailboxer::Conversation'
```

or

```
- elsif object.class == Mailboxer::Conversation
```

HTH